# Mongoose - "ValidationError:xxx:" when receiving JSON body

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was trying to insert new document to my collection with schema and router as follows:

```js
SCHEMA

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const activitySchema = new Schema({
    date: { type: String, required: true},
    type: { type: String, required: true},
    text: { type: String, required: true},
    members: { type: String, required: true}
});

const Activity = mongoose.model('Activity', activitySchema);

module.exports = Activity;
```

```js
ROUTER

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const dateP = req.body.date;
    const typeP = req.body.type;
    const textP = req.body.text;
    const membersP = req.body.members;
    const newActivity = new Activity({
        date: dateP,
        type: typeP,
        text: textP,
        members: membersP
    });

    newActivity.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Activity added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

But when I send JSON body through POSTMAN, I get the following error:

```html
"Error: ValidationError: date: Path `date` is required., type: Path `type` is required., text: Path `text` is required., members: Path `members` is required."
```

And my body:

```
{
    "date": "2020-01-29",
    "type": "Night Course",
    "text": "Biology",
    "members": "Class 9a"
}
```

But when I use x-www-form-urlencoded with body-parser package, it works. What is going on? Why can't I get the value from my JSON file?

Edit:
This is the body-parser that I am using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.raw());
```

But still, only urlencoded that works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, everything works fine if you use body-parser and it doesn't work if you don't use it.

If yes, you probably get the value from Postman, but you need to use body-parser anyway.

body-parser parse the body of your request AND make it available through req.body. So if you don't use it, your variable (dateP, etc...) are probably undefined, which would explain why you get this error.

Comment: There I updated my body-parser that I am using. But still doesn't work for JSON. In my router, I use all of my placeholder (dateP etc.) to retrieve value from each req.body, which explains why it work using urlencoded.

Comment: In postman, in the body tab, did you check "raw" AND select "JSON" ?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to change it. Geez, thanks and excuse my carelessness.